# Digital Ocean Spaces - Root Domain instead of Subdomain

Tags: cloud, cdn, digital-ocean

Digital ocean spaces support subdomain such as

product.example.com/image

But I want to use it with **Root Domain** instead of subdomain such as

example.com/image

Can anyone give me some helpful instruction how can I set it up.

Thank you

Comment: This seems like a good question for digital ocean support.